# What is a good in-emacs process for finding emacs function names and keystrokes

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I am learning emacs and I think developing facility with emacs's built in help features would really smooth out the learning curve for learning keystrokes.

What is an efficient process, using emacs's built-in help functions, to find the name of a command and its keystroke?

For example, I've forgotten the key stroke for closing a frame. So I press C-h f and type in frame. I don't see any obvious candidates for the function that closes a frame, so I run a search on google.

Is there a better plan b than search google built into emacs? Alternatively, is there a better plan a than C-h f for finding the keystroke for a function whose name I cannot remember?

I've also installed helm.

Edit: All three suggestions were an improvement on my current emacs help doc search process, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `apropos-command`, bound to `C-h a` by default.

For example, `C-h a frame RET` shows commands containing the word `frame`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have helm, `helm-M-x` is a great way to find/execute commands and learn about keystrokes. It is a great replacement for the standard `M-x`. On the other hand if you know your keystroke, but want to find out which command corresponds to it, `describe-key-briefly`, typically on `C-h c` works great.

Answer (score 4):

I think Chris's `apropos-command` is generally a good approach, but if you want something slightly more compact, you can do:

```
M-x *frame TAB
```

or

```
C-h f *frame TAB
```

The first shows (in the `*Completions*` buffer) all commands with "frame" in their name, and the second does the same for functions.  You can then use Isearch in the *Completions* buffer if the list is too long.  You can also do

```
M-x *close*frame TAB
```

to see if there's a command whose name includes "close" and "frame" (in this order).